# Replace values of certain column and rows in a DataFrame with the value of another column in the same dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

i want to replace value in "categori" column from index 155 to 304 with "keterangan" column with the same index, here is my dataset looks like :

[image]

i already try this but it doesnt work

```
# make a variabel with value from 155 to 304
ket_list = list(range(155,305))

# Selecting new value
new = df['keterangan'][ket_list]
new

# Selecting old value
old = df['categori'][ket_list]
old

# replace values of "categori" value with
# "keterangan" value from the same dataframe
df = df.replace(['old'],'new')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can make it work

```
df.loc[155:305,'categori'] = df['keterangan']
```

This will copy the values from `keterangan` to `categori` only on the index from `155` to `305`

Comment: let me know if this is helping out